# Plot time data in R to various resolutions (to the minute, to the hour, to the second, etc.)

Tags: r, time, statistics, plot

I have some data in CSV like:

```
"Timestamp", "Count"
"2009-07-20 16:30:45", 10
"2009-07-20 16:30:45", 15
"2009-07-20 16:30:46", 8
"2009-07-20 16:30:46", 6
"2009-07-20 16:30:46", 8
"2009-07-20 16:30:47", 20
```

I can read it into R using read.cvs. I'd like to plot:

1. Number of entries per second, so:

   ```
   "2009-07-20 16:30:45", 2
   "2009-07-20 16:30:46", 3
   "2009-07-20 16:30:47", 1
   ```
2. Average value per second:

   ```
   "2009-07-20 16:30:45", 12.5
   "2009-07-20 16:30:46", 7.333
   "2009-07-20 16:30:47", 20
   ```
3. Same as 1 & 2 but then by Minute and then by Hour.

Is there some way to do this (collect by second/min/etc & plot) in R?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read your data, and convert it  into a [**zoo**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) object:

```
R> X <- read.csv("/tmp/so.csv")
R> X <- zoo(X$Count, order.by=as.POSIXct(as.character(X[,1])))
```

Note that this will show warnings because of non-unique timestamps.

Task 1 using `aggregate` with `length` to count:

```
R> aggregate(X, force, length)
2009-07-20 16:30:45 2009-07-20 16:30:46 2009-07-20 16:30:47 
                  2                   3                   1
```

Task 2 using `aggregate`:

```
R> aggregate(X, force, mean)
2009-07-20 16:30:45 2009-07-20 16:30:46 2009-07-20 16:30:47 
             12.500               7.333              20.000
```

Task 3 can be done the same way by aggregating up to higher-order indices.  You can call `plot` on the result from aggregate:

```
plot(aggregate(X, force, mean))
```

Comment: Nice! I had to add the Zoo package in the Package Manager and call "library(zoo)" first.

Comment: Yes, that's how it works with packages.  For your hourly etc indices, use the 'parsed time' (here:  index(X)  after zoo object has been created) and created an 'aggregation index vector' that you use in aggregate:  
  R> aggind <- format(index(X), "%Y%m%d %H%m")
  R> aggregate(X, aggind, mean)
  20090720 1607 
        11.17 
Exactly the same works for other indices (change the formatting rule) and functions (replace mean by whatever you need).

Comment: Again, nice!  I noticed, when I make an aggregation index vector like: R> aggind <- format(index(hx), "%Y-%m-%d %H%M") I can only plot via boxplot(aggregate(X, aggind, mean)) and not via plot(aggregate(X, aggind, mean)).  plot(...) returns "Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values".

Comment: Assign the temp. result to a variable and run summary() over it -- you may have NAs which throws some of the plotting off.

Answer (score 2):

Averaging the data is easy with the plyr package.

```
library(plyr)
Second <- ddply(dataset, "Timestamp", function(x){
    c(Average = mean(x$Count), N = nrow(x))
})
```

To do the same thing by minute or hour, then you need to add fields with that info.

```
library(chron)
dataset$Minute <- minutes(dataset$Timestamp)
dataset$Hour <- hours(dataset$Timestamp)
dataset$Day <- dates(dataset$Timestamp)
#aggregate by hour
Hour <- ddply(dataset, c("Day", "Hour"), function(x){
    c(Average = mean(x$Count), N = nrow(x))
})
#aggregate by minute
Minute <- ddply(dataset, c("Day", "Hour", "Minute"), function(x){
    c(Average = mean(x$Count), N = nrow(x))
})
```