# How to select and plot hourly averages from data frame?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a CSV file that looks like this, where "time" is a UNIX timestamp:

```
time,count
1300162432,5
1299849832,0
1300006132,1
1300245532,4
1299932932,1
1300089232,1
1299776632,9
1299703432,14
... and so on
```

I am reading it into R and converting the time column into POSIXct like so:

```
data <- read.csv(file="data.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")
data[,1] <- as.POSIXct(data[,1], origin="1970-01-01")
```

Great so far, but now I would like to build a histogram with each bin corresponding to the average hourly count.  I'm stuck on selecting by hour and then counting.  I've looked through `?POSIXt` and `?cut.POSIXt`, but if the answer is in there, I am not seeing it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256347/plot-time-data-in-r-to-various-resolutions-to-the-minute-to-the-hour-to-the-se

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
R> lines <- "time,count
1300162432,5
1299849832,0
1300006132,1
1300245532,4
1299932932,1
1300089232,1
1299776632,9
1299703432,14"
R> con <- textConnection(lines); df <- read.csv(con); close(con)
R> df$time <- as.POSIXct(df$time, origin="1970-01-01")
R> df$hour <- as.POSIXlt(df$time)$hour
R> df
                 time count hour
1 2011-03-15 05:13:52     5    5
2 2011-03-11 13:23:52     0   13
3 2011-03-13 09:48:52     1    9
4 2011-03-16 04:18:52     4    4
5 2011-03-12 12:28:52     1   12
6 2011-03-14 08:53:52     1    8
7 2011-03-10 17:03:52     9   17
8 2011-03-09 20:43:52    14   20
R> tapply(df$count, df$hour, FUN=mean)
 4  5  8  9 12 13 17 20 
 4  5  1  1  1  0  9 14 
R>
```

Your data doesn't actually yet have multiple entries per hour-of-the-day but this would average over the hours, properly parsed from the POSIX time stamps.  You can adjust with TZ info as needed.

Comment: Beautiful!  After posting, I came up with a way using c, subset, and mean, but I had to have a subset and mean call for every 'bin'.  This is much easier to understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the hour "bin" for each time by converting to a `POSIXlt` and subtracting away the minute and seconds components.  Then you can add a new column to your data frame that would contain the hour bin marker, like so:

```
date.to.hour <- function (vec)
{
    as.POSIXct(
        sapply(
            vec,
            function (x)
            {
                lt = as.POSIXlt(x)
                x - 60*lt$min - lt$sec
            }),
        tz="GMT",
        origin="1970-01-01")
}

data$hour <- date.to.hour(as.POSIXct(data[,1], origin="1970-01-01"))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a good post on this topic on [Mages' blog](http://lamages.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/say-it-in-r-with-by-apply-and-friends.html). To get the bucketed data:

```
aggregate(. ~ cut(time, 'hours'), data, mean)
```

If you just want a quick graph, [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org/) is your friend:

```
qplot(cut(time, "hours"), count, data=data, stat='summary', fun.y='mean')
```

Unfortunately, because cut returns a factor, the x axis won't work properly. You may want to write your own, less awkward bucketing function for time, e.g.

```
timebucket = function(x, bucketsize = 1,
                      units = c("secs", "mins",  "hours", "days", "weeks")) {
  secs = as.numeric(as.difftime(bucketsize, units=units[1]), units="secs")
  structure(floor(as.numeric(x) / secs) * secs, class=c('POSIXt','POSIXct'))
}
qplot(timebucket(time, units="hours"), ...)
```